# Unhandled exception after reading histogram (created with calcHist)

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram, unhandled-exception

I am trying to get histogram from my color (3-channel) image in OpenCV but every time I do the calcHist histogram like this :

```
//int histSize[3];
//float hranges[2];
//const float* ranges[3];
//int channels[3];

ColorHistogram::ColorHistogram() 
{
    // Prepare arguments for a color histogram
    histSize[0]= histSize[1]= histSize[2]= 256;
    hranges[0]= 0.0; // BRG range
    hranges[1]= 255.0;
    ranges[0]= hranges; // all channels have the same range
    ranges[1]= hranges;
    ranges[2]= hranges;
    channels[0]= 0; // the three channels
    channels[1]= 1;
    channels[2]= 2;
}

cv::MatND ColorHistogram::getHistogram(const cv::Mat &image)
{
    cv::MatND hist;
    // Compute histogram
    cv::calcHist(&image,
        1, // histogram of 1 image only
        channels, // the channel used
        cv::Mat(), // no mask is used
        hist, // the resulting histogram
        3, // it is a 3D histogram
        histSize, // number of bins
        ranges // pixel value range
        );
    return hist;
}
```

[image]

When I try to fed the result to for instance `cv::minMaxLoc` I get an unhandled exception.

```
cv::Mat ColorHistogram::getHistogramImage(const cv::Mat &image){
    // Compute histogram first
    cv::MatND hist = getHistogram(image);
    // Get min and max bin values
    double maxVal=0;
    double minVal=0;
    cv::minMaxLoc(hist, &minVal, &maxVal, 0, 0);
//....
}
```

**EDIT**

I don't know if this is important but I get this error in console:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (img.dims <= 2) in unknown function,
>   file
>   C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\stat.cpp,
>   line 788

and my `image`'s `dims = 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `minMaxLoc` with a 3D histogram (i.e., `hist.dims == 3` is true) unfortunately. Below is the code for `minMaxLoc`:

```
void cv::minMaxLoc( InputArray _img, double* minVal, double* maxVal,
                Point* minLoc, Point* maxLoc, InputArray mask )
{
    Mat img = _img.getMat();
    CV_Assert(img.dims <= 2); // <-- This is the line that is asserting for you...

    minMaxIdx(_img, minVal, maxVal, (int*)minLoc, (int*)maxLoc, mask);
    if( minLoc )
        std::swap(minLoc->x, minLoc->y);
    if( maxLoc )
        std::swap(maxLoc->x, maxLoc->y);
}
```

You'll have to search for the min and max values in your 3D histogram manually. You may be able to use the [NAryMatIterator](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=narymatiterator#NAryMatIterator) to help ease the search. There is an example of how to use this with the documentation. Also, you can find my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809517/multi-dimensional-data-in-a-matrix-in-opencv-with-c/8809877#8809877).