# Packaging python and scipy with a C++ binary

Tags: python, c++, scipy, boost-python

I have a Windows C++ application from which I would like to call python's scipy package to perform certain image processing functions. I would also like to include the necessary python interpreter and additional packages (numpy, scipy) along with the executable so that the user does not have to install anything.

Is this possible and what is the simples way to do it? Would it be possible with something like Boost/Python?

Comment: Try it. See [Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html). Supports numpy. Don't know about scipy.

Comment: Of course it is possible to package up that stuff. Learn how to build an installer or just throw everything in a zip file depending on how fancy you want/need to be.

Comment: Btw., for image processing in C++ I would use OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @ypnos I actually need to process 3D volumes so scipy's ndimage module comes handy.

Comment: @pseudomarvin OpenCV has added support for nd arrays some years ago, see for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809517/multi-dimensional-data-in-a-matrix-in-opencv-with-c Constructor is here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a156df5a1326dd5c30b187b0e721a5f57 Just in case you didn't know, it might be helpful for you.

Comment: @ypnos Yeah thanks, I know about that, unfortunately there is not support for the functionality that I require in OpenCV (e.g., affine transforms for 3D volumes) so it does not help that much.