# How can I create separate cv::Mat headers for the channels of an image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 4.1.1. and have the following goal

> Given a `Mat` of size (m, n, 2) of float32, create separate `Mat` headers for each individual channel, so that it can be written to, without copying the image data

What I am trying to do is this:

```
  const int mat_sz[]{shape_.height, shape_.width, 2};
  Mat cost(3, mat_sz, CV_32F);

  Mat channel1(
      shape_, CV_32FC1,  /* 1 channel Mat has FC1 type*/
      cost.ptr<float>(), /* data ptr */
      cost.step[2] * 2 /* orig stride/step should be 4 for float, x2 because
                          we want every  other */
  );
  channel1(Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)) = 255;

  Mat channel2(
      shape_, CV_32FC1, cost.ptr<float>() + 1, // +1 so we start at the  second channel  element
      cost.step[2] * 2);
  channel2(Rect(0, 0, 100, 100)) = 128;
```

I can see by `normalize`ing  and `imshow`ing  the two channels that

- rectangle selection seems not to  work in this  case, instead pixels get filled from  the  top, maybe `operator(Rect)` doesnt do what I want in this case.
- the values  which should go into  channel 2 show up in channel 1 and vise versa

What am I doing wrong?

---

I'm using this code to display the matrix:

```
#define DISPLAY(m)                                                             \
  {                                                                            \
    Mat _tmp##m;                                                               \
    normalize(m, _tmp##m, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);                                  \
    imshow(#m, _tmp##m);                                                       \
    waitKey(0);                                                                \
  }
```

Comment: that's not possible, because of the memory layout and direct access. If opencv wasn't optimized for speed ot could implement it by defining a channel step value (the distance between two pixels in memory). But now you can only use the split and merge functions, which are using clones.

Comment: But then what good is the step parameter for a matrix if it's not used? Or is the calculation wrong? Channel values for each pixel are laid out one after the other, so according to the documentation, this should work I think.

Comment: Or  are you saying its only the row step that's really used, and the assumption is that cols and channels are always contiguous?

Comment: If the above doesnt work, I'm wondering  how `NAryMatIterator` works, unless it does somehow copy, in which case this answer here would not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8809877/2397253

Comment: On further consideration, the doc does say for the step  parameter for multidimensional `Mat`s: `Array of ndims-1 steps in case of a multi-dimensional array (the last step is always set to the element size)`. So there seems to be the assumption of the last (channel) dimension to be contiguous.

Comment: I only know about the row-step, which is used for efficient sub-imaging and padded data for SSE instructions. If there is an element-step, maybe you can use it with elrment-iterators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible, because [the documentation for the `cv::Mat` constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a5fafc033e089143062fd31015b5d0f40) taking in number dimension, their sizes and preallocated data states that

> `steps`:  Array of ndims-1 steps in case of a multi-dimensional array (the **last step is always set to the element size**). If not specified, the matrix is assumed to be continuous.

So the last dimension cannot be strided and is always assumed to be contiguous in memory. A value passed for this dimension is ignored.